# How to set overflow to hidden on img tag if its position is absolute

Tags: html, css

In my html I have the following

```
<article class="innovate">
    <img src="img/entrepreneur-593358.jpg" />
    <h1>We Innovate</h1>
</article>
```

And its CSS

```
.innovate {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -140px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

    .innovate img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        height: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .innovate h1 {
        padding-top: 230px;
        font-size: 80px;
    }
```

I have tried a few things to make the overflow: hidden in the img tag work
but for some reason it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to crop your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to crop your image programmatically, I would recommend using the CSS `clip` property, which will clip an absolutely positioned element. The arguments specified are the top, right, bottom, and left coordinates of the rectangle to clip to.

The following example code will clip your image to be 60px wide and 200px tall:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```